# How to write data on multiple lines BUT within the same cell of csv?

Tags: c#, csv

I want to create one csv file using C#.

I have some data which I want to write on multiple lines BUT within the same cell.

For example 
If I have following three sentences,

```
Sample sentence 1. This is second sample sentence. and this is third sentence.
```

I want to write all these three sentences within single cell of csv file but I want three of them on separate line.

My expected output is :

```
Sample sentence 1.
This is second sample sentence.
and this is third sentence.
```

Currently I am trying to achieve this by using `\n` character between two sentences but when I do it this way, all three sentences go on separate row.

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To [quote Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

> Fields with embedded line breaks must
>   be enclosed within double-quote
>   characters.

Like e.g.:

```
1997,Ford,E350,"Go get one now
they are going fast"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to change which tokens your application uses to parse rows from the csv file, but according to the [definition of the csv file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), lines in the file are used to represent rows in the resulting tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "...";

var r = input.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) // split by dot (have you any better approaches?)
             .Select(s => String.Format("\"{0}.\"", s.Trim())); // escape each with quotes

input = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, r); // break by line break
```

Answer (score 0):

Always wrap your description in between "\" eg: CsvRow.Add("\"" + ID + " : " + description + "\"");

Answer (score 0):

```
string filePath = @"d:\pandey.csv";
StringBuilder outString=new StringBuilder();
outString.Append("\""); //double quote 
outString.Append("Line 1, Hi I am line 1 of same cell\n");
outString.Append("Line 2 Hi I am line 2 of same cell\n");
outString.Append("Line 3 Hi I am line 3 of same cell\n");
outString.Append("Line 4 Hi I am line 4 of same cell");
outString.Append("\""); //double quote             
File.WriteAllText(filePath, outString.ToString());
```

Comment: Please add comment to your code to explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but none of the above solutions completely worked for me.

I am working on an Event log tool where events have multiline description. I initially used comma as a delimiter and enclosed description in double quotes however it did not work.

I changed the delimited from comma to tab and now it works perfectly fine.

```
// Replace double quotes in description with empty character to avoid unexpected line breaks in CSV file
Description = Description.Replace("\"", "");

line = $"{Level}\t{Computer}\t{EvtDateTime}\t{EventID}\t{Source}\t{Provider}\t{Category}\t{User}\t\"{Description}\"";

outfile.WriteLine(line);
```

The way I figured it out is by opening the CSV file in MS Excel, did the text to column using comma and saved it. Opened it in Notepad++ and found the comma's are now replaced with tabs.

I think it depends on what delimiter is used by default but I was not able to figure it out how to change it. Every search result I get points to Windows region settings but I do not see tab anywhere.

I am on windows 11 and using MS Excel for Microsoft 365.

Answer (score -2):

CSV stands for "comma seperated values" which is just a description of a text-file. If you want to import into Excel and then only have the sentences in one line you should try:

```
Environment.NewLine
```

instread of a simple `/n`