# var [][] array remove specific words

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, remove-if

I got a little Problem. I have a .csv with "NaN" values and doubles (0.6034 for example) and I am trying to read just the doubles of the CSV into an array[y][x].

Currently, i read the whole .csv, but I can not manage to remove all "NaN" values afterward. (It should parse through the CSV and just add the Numbers to an array[y][x] and leave all "NaN" out)

My current Code:

```
 var rows = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Select(l => l.Split(';').ToArray()).ToArray(); //reads WHOLE .CSV to array[][]


        int max_Rows = 0, j, rank;
        int max_Col = 0;
        foreach (Array anArray in rows)
        {
            rank = anArray.Rank;
            if (rank > 1)
            {
                 // show the lengths of each dimension
                for (j = 0; j < rank; j++)
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
            // show the total length of the entire array or all dimensions

            max_Col = anArray.Length; //displays columns
            max_Rows++;  //displays rows
        }
```

I tried the search but couldn't really find anything that helped me.
I know this is probably really easy but I am new to C#.

### The .CSV and the desired outcome:

```
NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN
NaN;1;5;NaN
NaN;2;6;NaN
NaN;3;7;NaN
NaN;4;8;NaN
NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN
```

This is a sample .csv i have. I should have been more clear, sorry! There is a NaN in every line. and i want it to display like this:

```
1;5
2;6
3;7
4;8
```

This is just a sample of the .csv the real csv has arround 60.000 Values... I need to get the input with [y][x] for example [0][0] should display "1" and [2][1] should displays "7" and so on.

Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: BTW, I would _never ever_ dare to make my own CSV parser. Way to many edge cases ([e.g.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6516246/107625)), IMO.

Comment: @Uwe Keim: I agree with you, that in *general case* CSV can well appear complex enough; however, when CSV source is *known* (say, my own routine which exports data from RDMBS for future analysis) or in case of single-use software (all I want is to remove incomplete rows and perform linear regression on the CSV provided) I'll be more indulgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all the lines that contain `NAN` (typical task for CSV - clearing up all *incomplete lines*), e.g.

```
  123.0; 456; 789
    2.1; NAN;  35     <- this line should be removed (has NaN value)
     -5;   3;  18
```

You can implement it like this

```
  double[][] data = File
    .ReadLines(filepath)
    .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] {';', '\t'},
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Where(items => items  // Filter first...
       .All(item => !string.Equals("NAN", item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    .Select(items => items
       .Select(item => double.Parse(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
       .ToArray()) // ... materialize at the very end
    .ToArray();
```

Use `string.Join` to display rows:

```
 string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, data
   .Select(line => string.Join(";", line)));

 Console.Write(report);
```

**Edit:** The actual problem is to take 2nd and 3rd complete columns only from the CSV:

```
NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN
NaN;1;5;NaN
NaN;2;6;NaN
NaN;3;7;NaN
NaN;4;8;NaN
NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN
```

desired outcome is

```
[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

implmentation:

```
double[][] data = File
  .ReadLines(filepath)
  .Select(line => line
     .Split(new char[] {';'},
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     .Skip(1) 
     .Take(2)
     .Where(item => !string.Equals("NAN", item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     .ToArray())
  .Where(items => items.Length == 2)
  .Select(items => items
    .Select(item => double.Parse(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .ToArray())
  .ToArray();
```

Tests

```
// 1
Console.Write(data[0][0]);
// 5
Console.Write(data[0][1]);
// 2
Console.Write(data[1][0]);
```

All values in one go:

```
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, data
   .Select(line => string.Join(";", line)));

Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
1;5
2;6
3;7
4;8
```

**Edit 2**: if you want to extract non NaN values only (please, notice that the initial CSV structure will be **ruined**):

```
1;2;3              1;2;3
NAN;4;5            4;5   <- please, notice that the structure is lost
6;NAN;7        ->  6;7
8;9;NAN;           8;9
NAN;10;NAN         10
NAN;NAN;11         11
```

then

```
double[][] data = File
  .ReadLines(filepath)
  .Select(line => line
     .Split(new char[] {';'},
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     .Where(item => !string.Equals("NAN", item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
  .Where(items => items.Any()) 
  .Select(items => items
    .Select(item => double.Parse(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .ToArray())
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but i am getting an Error on this one i can not solve just yet:"
Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'string.Equals(string, System.StringComparison)' C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Test.cs 734 22 WindowsFormsApplication1

Btw. i do not want to remove the whole line, just the NaN itself

Comment: @christian890: I'm sorry for typo: `string.Equals("NAN", item...` we should compare `NAN` and `item`

Comment: Ahh thanks, it works now without mistakes but i have the same Problem as above. when i use "  MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(rows[0][0]));" it displays: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

it looks like something is wrong with my .csv but i cant figure out what it is

Comment: @christian890: could you, please, provide the CSV?

Comment: @christian890: as far as I can see from the CSV you've provided to **scartag**: `NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN 
NaN;1;5;NaN 
NaN;2;6;NaN 
NaN;3;7;NaN 
NaN;4;8;NaN 
NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN` *all* the lines have at least one `NAN` that's why the result array `data` is *empty*

Comment: @christian890: could you, please, *edit* your question: provide the test CSV and the desired outcome.

Comment: Done. I think as Dmitry pointed out could be the mistake, I am sorry to be unspecific, thanks for your help!

Comment: This is just a sample of the .csv the real csv has arround 60.000 Values... I need to get the input with   [y][x]  for example [0][0] should display "1" and [2][1] should displays "7"

Comment: @christian890: I see; if you want to extract 2nd and 3d complete lines then see my edit; since `data` is a jagged array you cane obtain the items required as you want: `data[x][y]`, e.g. `data[0][0]` should return `1`

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect for the Dummy. But if i use the real  .csv  with more "NaN" lines and columns before any values i have the "Index out of array" error again =/ Problem is i cant say in which line i have "NaN" values, i need to read the actual Value of the csv and skip it if its "NaN" if its not, write it to array, and this for every value in the .csv

Comment: This should work perfect, I dont mind loosing the structure (if there is 1 Nan value the whole line OR column is NaN -> all in all the structure will be the same)
just 1 problem with the code:
"
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The input character string has wrong format"

i get on ".Select(item => double.Parse(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))" this line, you may know why?

Thank you so much!!! i think you saved my day ! =)

Comment: @christian890: The cause of the error is that a value within CSV is neither `NaN` not valid `double` value, e.g. `"bla-bla-bla"`. Could you, please, provide the actual CSV file?

Comment: this is the whole csv: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/8b4139e47847443ef153ef6583056771/measurements.csv or http://textuploader.com/drhq8

Comment: I managed to delimit the error, it appears that if i delete the last column of the csv it works... so i guess it is something about the last character?

Edit: the Problem is an empty field! if i have NaN;;NaN i get this error asap! and in the .CSV i get from the system the last field is empty. How can i fix this? THANKS!!!!

Comment: @christian890: you have to remove not only `NaN`, but empty values as well - `.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: @christian890: You are welcome! Next time, please, start with actual data :)

Answer (score 6):

You could do a filter of your delimited values in the array.

I've modified your code a bit.

```
 File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Select(l => l.Split(';').ToArray().Where(y => y != "NaN").ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: This looks good but i got some weird "error" when i use this and try to check the results by showing the 1. Value of the array -> MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(rows[0][0]))   it says "false" and for MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(rows[10][10])) "true" instead of the numbers, what am i doing wrong here? Your solution should work i think its really simple =) Thanks

Comment: You don't want `ReadAllLines` (premature materialization), `ReadLines` will be a better choice

Comment: @christian890 i've modified the code a bit. there was an error cause i wasn't testing with any data and used `select` instead of a `where`

Comment: `.ToArray()` in the `Split(';').ToArray()` is *redundant* since `Split(';')`returns an *array*

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. But i can not get it work just yet.
I use the Code with "where(y =>..." and then try to check the outputs with "MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(rows[0][0]));  // displays nothing (empty)
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(rows[0][1])); // ERROR out of Array 
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(rows[1][0]));"
This is weird, without the "where." there were no dimensions error

Comment: @christian890 might help to share a few rows of your csv

Comment: NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1 1 1 1
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1 1 1 1
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1 1 1 1
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1 1 1 1
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1 1 1 0.9782
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.6821 0.6976 0.6862 0.7017
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.9407 0.951 0.9588 0.9758
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.7132 0.7216 0.7364 0.7289
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.6254 0.6216 0.629 0.6493
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.6427 0.6349 0.6451 0.6877
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.5033 0.4994 0.4934 0.5079

Comment: oh sorry, thats because i opened it with excel..
aN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;
NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0.8627;0.7224;0.6194;0.5598;0.5146;0.4292;0.3843;0.3778;0.3532;0.2883;0.335;0.4728;0.6538;0.8563;0.9614;0.9056;0.827;0.7641;0.6197;0.4731;0.3603;0.279;0.2894;0.2924;0.3055;0.2956;0.3114;0.3061;0.2828;0.2689;0.2367;0.1968;0.2111;0.3458;0.3421;0.3291;0.3136;0.2969;0.2312;0.2121;0.1908;0.2031;0.1994;0.2152;0.2185;NaN;NaN;NaN

Comment: @christian890 i tried your values and it worked for me... although i got a lot of special characters within the values .. maybe cause i copied it from the page or something.

Comment: Thas weird... I get: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe" for [0][1] or [1][0] and [0][0] displays nothing =/ 

This code or? " var rows = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Select(l => l.Split(';').ToArray().Where(f => f != "NaN").ToArray()).ToArray();"

Comment: @christian890 i'm wondering if you could create a new csv by hand just to test the code and then check that the actual csv has the right newline characters required  .. i'm sure there is something wrong with the file and its content.

Comment: Thank you for your time i really appreciate it.
I tried that just now and the error gets even weirder. I get the "index is out of array" already when i want to display [0][0]... The .Csv i used this time: (hand made)

NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN
NaN;1;5;NaN
NaN;2;6;NaN
NaN;3;7;NaN
NaN;4;8;NaN
NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN

Comment: I just checked it with "var rows = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Select(l => l.Split(';').ToArray()).ToArray();" it works but of course all "NaN" are still there but with this i have no problems with the csv and with "var rows = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Select(l => l.Split(';').ToArray().Where(f => f != "NaN").ToArray()).ToArray();" it says  index out of array.... weird